# SQL Server CE date stored in string : how to compare

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a database in which, I see that dates are stored in the form of strings. Would it be possible for me to compare those date (in the form of string ) in a query?

For eg. column `date1` stores `09-11-1992 00:00:00` and `date2` stores `22-11-1992 00:00:00`

Would it be sensible to execute a query as follows:

```
select * from tablename WHERE date1 > "06-11-1992 00:00:00";
```

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are in a recognizable format, you should be able to [cast](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450.aspx) them to datetimes and compare.

```
select *
from tablename
where cast(date1 as datetime) > cast('06-11-1992 00:00:00' as datetime)
```

However, I'd recommend [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for dates.  Here's one possibility:

```
cast('1992-11-06T00:00:00' as datetime)
```

I'm assuming DD-MM-YYYY here because of your `date2` example.

Just be sure you know which is the day and which is the month.  Hopefully your strings are always the same format and are in-line with your regional settings.

**Be careful**: you may have to [set the date format](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907) to get the right output from your data:

```
set dateformat dmy
select cast('06-11-1992 00:00:00' as datetime) -- returns 1992-11-06 00:00:00
set dateformat mdy
select cast('06-11-1992 00:00:00' as datetime) -- returns 1992-06-11 00:00:00
```